# How to open multiple tabs as soon as user click on submit button?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension should able to create at least 30 new tabs as soon as user click on submit button. As user click on submit button, it should open multiples new tabs.Anyone with solution will be highly appreciated.

The html code for button has been provided below.
input type="submit" value="Submit"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58212516/edit) this question and provide the code you have so far so we can help you :)

Comment: Assuming you know JavaScript and DOM (if not, learn it), declare a `content script` with a "click" listener that checks event's target and if it matches the HTML you want, it'll send a message to the `background script` that can use `chrome.tabs.create` to open the tabs. See the extensions API [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) for a quick tour where you can learn about the terms I've highlighted, see also [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).